# How to perform load test on Websockets using JMeter?

Tags: testing, websocket, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

How to use jmeter with Jetty WebSockets?
I mean can i perform a load-test on websockets using jmeter?
Is there any alternative tool other than jmeter to perform load test on jetty web sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative WebSocket plugin for JMeter supporting RFC6455 version of the WebSocket.

Hope it would come useful: http://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can at least try this one: [jmeter-websocket](https://github.com/kawasima/jmeter-websocket) - jmeter plugin for WebSocket protocol.

Comment: Well, there are no mentions in your question about attempts to use this plugin as well as about results of this usage.

Comment: Tried to get jMeter working and ultimately determined it was easier to kidnap 1,000 people and force them to access the application.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative tool which is dedicated to do load testing on websockets. It is named as [Thor](https://github.com/observing/thor).

Thanks to the developers for making it simple, light weight and opensource.

**EDIT:**

Thor seems to be a bit outdated. There is this giant called [Gatling](http://gatling.io/). 
They have a powerful and highly customizable engine. You have to write some basic coding with Scala to get this thing up and working. But this is reliably easy and their [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/http/websocket/) is quite simple.

There are forums for help too.

Comment: Now 2017 and didn't have much luck with thor.  npm package install failed.  Abandoned?